# How do I fix this memory leak monitor func to avoid maximum call stack loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was having trouble tracking down a memory leak in Node.js and wrote a func to monitor object and array size increases over time but my func infinitely loops. I wrote a provision into it to detect and not iterate circular structures, but I've made some silly mistake and can't figure out what.

```
//monitor.js

const isCircular = require("../funcs/is-circular.js");
module.exports = class {
  constructor() {

  }
  countObjContents(obj, count = 0) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) count += this.countObjContents(obj)
    else if (typeof obj == "object") {
      if (isCircular(obj)) {
        console.log("!!! is circular")
        count++;
      } else {
        console.log("not circular")
        Object.values(obj).forEach(prop => {
          if (isCircular(prop)) {
            console.log("!!! is circular")
            count++;
          } else {
            console.log("not circular")
            count += this.countObjContents(obj);
          }
        });
      }
    } else count++;
    return count;
  }
  watch(obj, name) {
    let count = false;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("monitoring", name)
      let newCount = this.countObjContents(obj)
      if (!count) count = newCount;
      else {
        console.log("object", name, "increased from", count, "properties to", newCount);
        count = newCount;
      }
    }, 5000);
  }
}

//is-circular.js

module.exports = (obj) => {
  try {
      JSON.stringify(obj);
  } catch (e) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

What stupid mistake did I make this time? It seems like simple code and the fact that I don't understand why it's infinite looping is embarrasing lol.

error:

```
countObjContents(obj, count = 0) {
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:6:19)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
    at module.exports.countObjContents (C:\Users\jonat\Documents\GitHub\emporos\js\classes\monitor.js:7:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop is calling countObjContents with the original obj
rather than the prop.

You are also re-invoking countObjContents in the first condition check.

```
  countObjContents(obj, count = 0) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) count += this.countObjContents(obj)
```

This part alone is an infinite loop

Comment: it's a late night coding I swear I looked this over a bunch and thought my circular ref code was the culprit. ;_;